# Detect that an application is locked

Tags: c#

I have an application developed in C # that sometimes is blocked, when it is blocked I have to restart it. I know if there is any way to detect if the application is frozen, close it and then restart.

Thank for all!

Comment: The solution is to fix your code so your application doesn't freeze.

Comment: Don't do blocking work in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it could be a third party programm you want to restart:
You restart a process in C# like so:

```
Process[] procs;
procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Name");
// Test to see if the process is not responding. 
if (!procs[0].Responding)
{
  procs[0].CloseMainWindow();
  procs[0].WaitForExit();
  procs[0].Start();
}
```

Otherwise please follow the hints provided in the comments.